# Can i emulate a CD-ROM through a USB cable to another computer?

Tags: boot, usb, cd, emulation

So I was wondering if anyone out there knew a way to do something like the following

1. Mount ISO/DVD on Host

2. share through a USB connection: Making the client think the USB connection is a native CD-ROM drive.

I know this can be done through a network (Not that I know how to do that) But I will ask that question separately, as to not confuse Google Searches.

Comment: It may be possible somehow, I know some small form factor pc/tablets have a mini-usb port for accessing files from another PC, and There are these devices in existence http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/elegantinvention/isostick-the-optical-drive-in-a-usb-stick http://www.zalman.com/eng/product/Product_Read.php?Idx=673 , some new android/tablet devices are using USB-OTG http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_on_the_go which lets the device be either master or slave. I suspect it is only a matter of time...

Comment: It is possible if 1) the USB host adapter of the computer offering the virtual drive can operate in client mode (depends mostly on the available driver) and 2) you can find (or write) software that emulates an optical USB drive. There are kernel modules that provide a framework to emulate arbitrary USB client devices.

Answer (score 1):

Afaik, you need hardware that supports USB OtG at least in "device" mode.

Most Android phones are designed to show their USB port as "mass storage" to a PC (nowadays it is more used with MTP protocol anyway, but the hardware is still there), and you can do what you need with an app called DriveDroid.

Such hardware is able to emulate ethernet (it is used for USB tethering, for example), and other things like a cd, a ethernet modem, and other stuff that is mostly used by 3g-4g usb dongles (modems).
The kernel feature that allows this is called "usb gadget" https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/usb/gadget_configfs.txt

Also look for Gateworks wiki page for "USB_OTG" http://trac.gateworks.com/wiki/USB_OTG

Answer (score -3):

No.  USB is a master/slave protocol therefore you can not connect two masters ( PCs ) together.  This is why the connectors are different.

Comment: So, theres not even a "Usb slave" mode/pci card/etc..

Comment: @TardisGuy, nope... closest thing is a laplink cable, but you have to use their software to transfer files.

Comment: The USB specification contains a wiring diagram for a USB-A/male to USB-A/male cable, and I found it in a specification document from June 2011.  The first USB 3.0 specification was published a few years prior and there's no indication this host-to-host communication was new in 2011.  Given the correct software, and a cable that complies with the USB 3.0 specification, a computer with a USB 3.0 port should be able to emulate a CD-ROM drive to another computer.